# using ^ (caret) inside the states in lex/flex

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I'll put up my lex code first(lex body only).

```
%%
ps     {BEGIN STATE1;}
.      ;
<STATE1>^[0-9]  print("number after ps".)
```

with this code I'm trying to match a number right after the letters "ps". Thats why I used ^ character.
But the code doesn't match any correct strings such as ps3, ps4fd,ps554 etc.
Then I removed the ^ and tried but then it worked but also matches strings like pserd7, psfh45,psfhdjh4er etc.

I know that I can solve the problem without using states (ps[0-9].*). But I have to do this with states. How can I fix this? thanks....

Answer (score 2):

> with this code I'm trying to match a number right after the letters "ps". Thats why I used ^ character

But ^ doesn't mean that. It means 'beginning of line'.

> I know that I can solve the problem without using states (ps[0-9].*). But I have to do this with states.

Why? Very strange requirement.

You need to add more  rules to cover the other possibilities. For example:

```
<STATE1>. { BEGIN INITIAL; }
```

But this depends on what else if anything is legal after 'ps'.